# Create new connection for each query?

Tags: php, mysql

**Note: I used Google Translator to write this**

I've always done the following to work with MySQL:

```
-> Open Connection to the database.
-> see details
-> Insert Data
-> another query
-> close Connection
```

I usually use the same connection to do various things before closing.
A friend who studies this in the IPN of Mexico mentioned to me that the right way (for safety) is to make a new connection for each query, for example:

```
-> Open Connection to the database.
-> see details
-> close Connection
-> Open Connection to the database.
-> Insert Data
-> close Connection
-> Open Connection to the database.
-> another query
-> close Connection
```

My question is, what is the right thing to do? My method has been to make the least amount of queries to the database, and only make a connection and keep it until it no longer serves me.

Additionally, is it possible to make a double insertion to a table? For example:

```
insert into table1(relacion) values([insert into tablaRelacionada(id) values("dato")]);
```

and that "relacion" is the inserted ID from the first query in "tablaRelacionada".

Comment: "for safety" --- what kind of safety?

Comment: you should keep the same connection open as long as you need it for 1 query or 10 queries. and no for the `insert into table1...`

Comment: As far as opening the connection for each query and what is "right" depends on the location of the server.  If you are accessing a database over a LAN, or on your same machine, then the security risk of keeping the connection open is minimal, and actually will have a significant improvement on the query time.  Opening a new connection each time will be preferred when you are going across the Internet.

Comment: I do not know, it means that leaving an open connection, a hacker can access, I know I should clean up the data from the forms, that the connection has nothing to do

Comment: the first method is better. closing connection on each query does not give you any security advantage it only decreases db performance and concurrency.

Comment: @dub stylee: "Opening a new connection each time will be preferred when you are going across the Internet." --- why? Do you realize it will bring **HUGE** overhead?

Comment: @Jorhel Reyes: "I do not know, it means that leaving an open connection, a hacker can access" --- it's silly. Next time one mentions "security" buzzword ask them to explain it.

Comment: I would try to design my software to make as few queries as possible to the database.  Obviously, I wouldn't want to be querying 100 times back to back, when I could possibly combine the queries into a single query to reduce the number of round-trips to the server.

Comment: @dub stylee: it has nothing to do with the question and your previous comment. "Opening a new connection each time will be preferred when you are going across the Internet." --- is a terrible advice.

Comment: Thanks, by the side of the connection to the database I remain calm.

Comment: If I had a MySQL on a different place first thing I would be looking into is to establish a safe communication line between the two, for instance by using OpenVPN and no, the myth your friend told would give you no help on security what so ever. Security is by properly making sure you have everything well configured, up to date and only the necessary channels open to public and this is only the top of the iceberg.

Comment: Maybe it got lost in translation, but "your friend" is an idiot.

Comment: @PeeHaa: it's so great we have a person here who can be that direct ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a separate connection per query is *at best* a great way to bog down both your application and database servers with needless overhead. There are three aspects I see raised here:

1. Efficiency
2. Application Security
3. Network Security

### 1. Efficiency

Short answer: Bad idea.

Oftentimes the overhead required to initialize the connection is far more than what is required to run the actual query. Your application is probably going to run orders of magnitude *slower* if you take a connection-per-query approach.

### 2. Application Security

Short answer: Generally a bad idea, but in the context of PHP completely unnecessary.

The only 'safety' issue I can think of here would be worrying about users accessing leftover temp tables, or session settings "bleeding" over. This is unlikely to happen unless you're using persistent connections which are not the default. As well, most temporary values in MySQL are stored per-connection, and unless you have some PHP code that written poorly [in a particular, strange, and seldom-recommended way, ie. sharing around DB singletons and accessing them strangely] then maybe if the planets align *just right* you might access some MySQL session-specific data in an unexpected way.

This is pretty much the same as [preemptive optimization](http://pivotallabs.com/preemptive-optimization/), and is not worth worrying about.

### 3. Network Security

Short answer: No. What? Just... *no*.

If you're worried about someone peeping in on your connections the solution is not to make more of them, it to make them *securely*. [MySQL supports SSL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/configuring-for-ssl.html), so use that if you're worried.

**TL;DR** No. Don't create separate connections per-query. Bad. Whoever told you this needs to go back to school.

---

### Multi-Table Insert

What you've quoted is not possible, you would want to do something along the lines of the following:

```
$dbh->query("INSERT tablaRelacionada(id) values('dato')");
$lastid = $dbh->lastInsertId();
$dbh->query("INSERT INTO table1(relacion) values($lastid);");
```

Assuming that the table `tablaRelacionada` has an AUTO_INCREMENT column which is what you're trying to get from the first query.

See: [`lastInsertId()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

Comment: Definitely have to go back to it, thanks for your replies, I was completely calm.

Comment: Also the use of VPN and limiting the IP's to prevent external access is a good option in case your MySQL server is not within the same IDC or Server and require those to be used.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not possible to insert rows into two different tables with a single `INSERT` statement.  (You can use a trigger to get it done, but that trigger will need to issue a separate `INSERT` statement... from the client side it will look like one statement, but on the server, there would be two `INSERT` statements executed.

---

If performance and scalability aren't concerns, then "churning" connections is workable. There's nothing necessarily "wrong" with creating a separate connection for each statement, but it's resource intensive. There is a lot of overhead in creating a new session. (It looks rather simple from the client side, but it requires a lot of work on the server side, in addition to the codepath on the client.)

Reusing existing connections is a common pattern. It's one of the biggest benefits of implementing "connection pool", to make it easy to reuse connections without "churning", repeatedly connecting and disconnecting from the database.

In terms of a separate connection for each SQL statement somehow increasing "safety", that's a bit of a stretch.

But I can see some benefit of having a freshly initialized session.

For example, if you reuse an existing session, you may not know what changes have been made in the session state. Any changes made previously are still "in effect". This would be things like session variable settings (e.g. timezone, characterset, autocommit, user defined variables) which could have an impact on the current statement. But within a single script, where you've gotten a fresh connection, you should know what changes have been made, so that shouldn't really be an issue. (This would be more of an issue with using connections from a pool, where the connections are shared by multiple processes. One process mucking with the timezone or characterset could cause a slew of problems for other processes that reuse the connection.)

Comment: @Jorhel Reyes: I added an answer to the question concerning syntax for a multi-table insert in MySQL. It's not possible.